# Find the number of perfect cubes of three-digit numbers such that they end in the digits 56

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am trying to solve this question:

> Find the number of perfect cubes of three-digit numbers such that they end in $56$.

I was able to solve this question and the answer was 18. I just want to know if there is a number theory background to this question/shortcut methods for solving questions of these types.

Comment: How did you count eighteen? That would be helpful to know to see if there is a more "number theoretic" approach than what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice first that the only numbers that matter are the two-digit numbers.
>   So for integers $a$ and $b$ we need
>   $$
>   (10a+b)^3 = 1000a^3 + 300a^2b + 30ab^2+b^3
> $$
>   to equal $\_56$. The only single-digit number such the it's cube ends in a six is $6$, so $b=6$. And since $6^3$ is $\_16$ we now need
>   $$\begin{align}
>   30ab^2 &= \_40 \\
>   3a(6)^2 &= \_4 \\
>   \_8a &= \_4 \\
> \end{align}$$ 
>   This only happens when $a=8$ or $a=3$, so the solution should only be the numbers of the form $\_86$ or $\_36$.

All I used to solve this problem was [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) (without using any of the terminology of modular arithmetic). Instead of drawing blanks wherever the digits don't matter, I could have just put nothing there and said we are working $\bmod 100$ or $\bmod 10$.

Comment: also of the form $ -36$. That would give a total of $18$

Comment: @Lozenges, yeah I just caught that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I told my friend Ruby about this problem ([see here](https://gist.github.com/d29dc8b4c42e8daa3b87b241ac7d525b))
and she gave me $18$ numbers as well.

```
1: (136)**3 = 2515456
2: (186)**3 = 6434856
3: (236)**3 = 13144256
4: (286)**3 = 23393656
5: (336)**3 = 37933056
6: (386)**3 = 57512456
7: (436)**3 = 82881856
8: (486)**3 = 114791256
9: (536)**3 = 153990656
10: (586)**3 = 201230056
11: (636)**3 = 257259456
12: (686)**3 = 322828856
13: (736)**3 = 398688256
14: (786)**3 = 485587656
15: (836)**3 = 584277056
16: (886)**3 = 695506456
17: (936)**3 = 820025856
18: (986)**3 = 958585256
```

She is really fast trying them out.
If slower guys like me can come up with the same answer I am still pondering.